# Method to Copy specific object of array to the same type array of another at specific location

Tags: java

I just want to Sort an array of Cards by its cardtype "one of four Spade, Heart, Club, Diamond" i.e Spades comes first

I made new array please solve it

```
private static void colorSort(Card temp[]){      
    Card arr[];             
    arr = new Card[13];            
    int loc=0;              
    for(Card x: temp){            
        if(x.cardType=="Spade"){           
            arr[0] = temp[x];    //this line giving error that "can't convert Card to                          int"`            
            loc++;           
        }    
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
arr[0] = temp[x];
```

to

```
arr[loc] = x;
```

The for loop puts a card in `x` you don't need to access the array again.

You also need to place the values in a new index, limited by the array size, which is 13.  if you do `arr[0]` you are always replacing the value in that index.  So, put the values in a new index in the array with `arr[loc]`

Answer (score 1):

You can't index an array by an object (the than an Integer) - you must use an `int`.

But you don't want to access the array, you want to use the object in the loop:

```
arr[0] = x;
```